# sqlite3 and Python: date modifier

Tags: python, date, sqlite

When modifying the date of a column on python with sqlite3 I receive the None value.

```
datetime(Date, '+4 months')
```

works, but

```
datetime(Date, '+' || Test || 'months')
```

does not and sends me back None value. Test is an integer datatype column.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a space before `months`:

```
% sqlite3
sqlite> select datetime('2018-02-13', '+' || 4 || ' months');
2018-06-13 00:00:00
sqlite> select datetime('2018-02-13', '+' || 4 || 'months'); 

sqlite>
```